# Can an international Blue Card holder take his non registered partner with him?

Tags: germany, eu, resident-permit, blue-card

A little more of background.

1. Two non EU citizens (Serbia)
2. Been in a relationship for 4 years
3. Any form of same sex relationship not recognized in Citizenship Country
4. One partner gets the Blue Card in Germany (Köln)
5. Can the other partner join?

What makes me be uncertain is [this](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/family/couple/de-facto-unions/index_en.htm)

Comment: Your link seems to apply to EU citizens, so it is not particularly relevant.  The question is first whether an unregistered partner can qualify either as a "spouse" or a "family member" under German immigration law.  I couldn't find anything to answer that question.  If so, then you'll be left with the task of proving that your relationship with your partner in fact qualifies.

Comment: One option could be to register your relationship or even marry in one EU country. Your country of origin's stance on the question can make that impossible in some places but not in others.

Answer (score 2):

No!
A long-term relationship is not sufficient.

[Partner aus einer eheähnlichen Lebensgemeinschaft haben keinen Anspruch auf einen Familiennachzug nach Deutschland.](http://www.zuwanderung.sachsen.de/akzess/16064.htm)

But:
[Same sex marriages, legally performed in other countries according to the local jurisdiction, are recognized as civil unions in Germany](https://www.lsvd.de/recht/ratgeber/auslaenderrecht/immigration-law.html#c11364)

You need to have a registered civil union:

[Beim Nachzug eines gleichgeschlechtlichen Lebenspartners muss es sich um eine "eingetragene Lebenspartnerschaft" im Sinne des deutschen Lebenspartnerschaftsgesetzes oder um eine nach ausländischem Recht staatlich anerkannte Lebenspartnerschaft handeln.](http://www.zuwanderung.sachsen.de/akzess/16064.htm)

If you are not married while having the blue card the spouse gets a visa as soon as your same sex marriage is registered: 
[Erfolgt die Eheschließung/Eingehen der Lebenspartnerschaft erst nach dem Zuzug, kann der Ehegatte/Lebenspartner grundsätzlich erst nach zwei Jahren Aufenthalt des Ausländers in Deutschland nachziehen. Bei Hochqualifizierten, Inhabern einer Blauen Karte EU sowie Forschern ist der Nachzug sofort möglich](http://www.zuwanderung.sachsen.de/akzess/16064.htm).

Here you can get further information via email:
https://www.lsvd.de/recht/beratung.html